# How to Get the Value of Selected Option in a Select Box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show an alert with the option selected but i can't see the popup alert with my form.

Here is my php:

```
<select class="form-control" id="status_users">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>Active</option>
  <option>Inactive</option>
  <option>Try</option>
</select>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(function SelectStatus(){
   $('#status_users').change(function () {
      var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
      alert(selected);
   });
});
```

What's wrong? thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.jQuery library need to be added before script code.

2.`$(function SelectStatus(){` need to be `$(function(){`

3.`alert(selected);` need to be `alert(selectedText);`

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(function(){
  $('#status_users').change(function(){
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    alert(selectedText);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="status_users">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>Active</option>
  <option>Inactive</option>
  <option>Try</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#status_users').change(function () {
        alert($("#status_users option:selected").text());
    });
});
```